# Kivy remove widget

Tags: python-2.7, widget, kivy

I'm having trouble removing a widgets with a label once it's added 
Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
    logi= True
    if data == []:

        logn =Label(text= "Incorrect Username",color=(190,0,0,1),
                     pos_hint={"right":1.035,"top":1.14})
        self.add_widget(logn)

        logu =Label(text= "Incorrect Password",color=(190,0,0,1),
                pos_hint={"right":1.035,"top":1.04})
        self.add_widget(logu)

        logi= False

    if logi == True:

        textinput.text=''
        textinput2.text=''

        if 'logn' in locals() and 'logu' in locals() :
            self.remove_widget(logn)   
            self.remove_widget(logu)
```

once the widgets have been added I can't seem to remove them, if i remove the `if 'logn' in locals() and 'logu' in locals() :`statement I get an error "Local variable referenced before assignment " every time I test this without the above mentioned if statment I make sure the widgets have been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are entering this method twice (1st data==[] 2nd time data=[...]). So You should keep your variables at hand (put them on the instance - *self*)

```
logi= True
if data == []:

    self.logn =Label(text= "Incorrect Username",color=(190,0,0,1),
                 pos_hint={"right":1.035,"top":1.14})
    self.add_widget(self.logn)

    self.logu =Label(text= "Incorrect Password",color=(190,0,0,1),
            pos_hint={"right":1.035,"top":1.04})
    self.add_widget(self.logu)

    logi= False

if logi == True:

    textinput.text=''
    textinput2.text=''

    if hasattr(self, 'logn'): #check that we put something here before...
        self.remove_widget(self.logn)   
        self.remove_widget(self.logu)
```

Note all the places I've added *self* ...